# How to compare time values in MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field with name `arrival_time` in a table of my MySQL database. Which function should be used to report if there is a difference of more than 5 minutes in a set of selected records in terms of `arrival_time`?

Comment: can you show what you have done?

Comment: What's the data type of that field?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask properly here. You need to put some effort first to your problem before you post any question and hoping someone doing your homework. :)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky that's a time field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Select the minimum and maximum `arrival_time`
2. Use an aggregate condition to establish a difference of more than five minutes between the values obtained from step 1.

So, this should work (untested):

```
SELECT MIN(arrival_time) AS min_time, MAX(arrival_time) AS max_time
FROM mytable
GROUP BY <xyz>
HAVING DATE_SUB(max_time, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) < min_time;
```

See also [`DATE_SUB()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

Answer (score 0):

If arrival_time is a UNIX timestamp, you can use that. Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(arrival_time) AS arrival_time
```

While your php to check for 5 minutes

```
if( strtotime('-5 minutes') < $row["arrival_time"] ) {
   echo "More than 5 minutes has elapsed";
}
```

Comment: it's not a UNIX timestamp.. :)